# Oracle instant client with gem ruby-oci8 not able to connect with DB in rails c

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, macos-mojave, oci8

I am using Oracle instant client in my project and using ruby-oci8 gem. I am using Mac Mojave OS

I am able to run the `rails server` and server does connect with database but when I run `rails c` and try to connect with any table it throws following error.

```
    Running via Spring preloader in process 95609
    Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.1)
    User.last
objc[96849]: +[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[96849]: +[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
/Users/arvindmehra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.5/lib/oci8/oci8.rb:142: [BUG] Illegal instruction at 0x007fff6efbf2e5
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

I am not able to connect with DB using rails console, strange thing is rails server is working and Application is able to connect with DB.

Comment: Hi, I have edit the question for clarity, my question is I am not able to connect with DB in Rails c when using Oracle instant client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve it by upgrading ruby version to `2.4.4` and adding  `export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES`. I guess issue is with Combination of `OSX Mojave` and `ruby-2.4.0` and its actually working for `OSX High Sierra`